# I am using laravel 8 with vue and got this error

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

webpack compiled with 1 error ERROR in ./resources/js/components/role.vue 2:0 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders | >  |

```
 <script>
export default {
  data() {enter code here
    return {
      permissions: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getPermissions() {
      axios
        .get("http://localhost:8000/getAllPermisison")
        .then((response) => {
          this.permissions = response.data.permissions;
        })
        .catch(() => {
          swal.fire({
            icon: "error",
            title: "Oops...",
            text: "Something went wrong!",
          })
        });
    }
  },
created(){
  this.getPermissions();
}
}
</script>>
```

Comment: probably need to add [vue-loader](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/) to your packages.json

Comment: `data() {enter code here` does not seem valid

Comment: i have added vue-loader file but still not working

Comment: "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "vue-html-loader": "^1.2.3",
        "vue-loader": "10.0.3",
        "webpack": "^2.2.1"

Comment: I don't know if this is actually in your code or not but the "enter code here" here will more than likely throw an error and you have an extra `>` at the end of your file. I'm not saying this is **the** problem but I thought I'd point it out :)

Comment: tried as you said but still getting error